# Exclude a file or package from the Clover report using ant build script

Tags: java, ant, clover

I am using a short ant script to generate my Clover coverage report. I want to exclude certain source files from the **report**. The code is already fully instrumented, it's not feasible for me to exclude the file during instrumentation.

Excerpt of the ant build xml (trimmed):

```
<project name="Clover Coverage" default="clover.report" basedir="${basedir}">
    <target name="clover.report">
        <clover-report initstring="${cloverdb}" >
            <current outfile="${reportdir}" title="${title}" >
                <format type="html"/>
                <sourcepath>
                    <pathelement path="${srcdir1}"/>
                </sourcepath>
            </current>
        </clover-report>
    </target>
</project>
```

I've tried to exclude this using `fileset`, but when I do this, Clover gives an error message saying that no coverage info could be found. But if I remove the fileset then it works fine.

My attempted fix that doesn't work:

```
            <current outfile="${reportdir}" title="${title}" >
                <format type="html"/>
                <fileset dir="${srcdir1}">
                    <exclude name="**/ExcludeThisClass.java"/>
                </fileset>
                <sourcepath>
                    <pathelement path="${srcdir1}"/>
                </sourcepath>
            </current>
```

Is the exclusion of files from the Clover report not possible?

Comment: An Ant `<fileset>` requires either a `dir` or `file` attribute. See what happens when adding `dir="${srcdir1}"` to the `<fileset>`.

Comment: @ChadNouis You're right, that's a typo in my copy-paste. I'll update the question. I was trying various things and I tried removing the `dir="${srcdir1}"`. When I have it in, it reports `[clover-report] No coverage recordings found. No report will be generated.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run your Ant with debug logging (ant -d). The <clover-report> task should print more details then. The most probably you instrumented and/or executed your source code not at once but in several build/test sessions.

And it's probable that Clover rejected some of recording files because it found them out of date.

See these knowledge base articles:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloverkb/ignoring-coverage-recording-files-300816998.html

https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloverkb/no-coverage-recordings-found-no-report-will-be-generated-611812757.html